# MYSQL: Return results ONLY for the first true encountered SELECT expression

Tags: mysql, sql, control-flow

## Desired result:

Return results ONLY for the first true encountered SELECT expression.

### Explanation:

So, I have three different SELECT expresions:

1. SELECT * FROM table WHERE  column1 = 'sometext' AND column2='1'
2. SELECT * FROM table WHERE  column1 = 'someothertext' AND column2='2'
3. SELECT * FROM table WHERE  column1 = 'somethirdtext' AND column2='3'

I want to have the results from 1. If 1. is returning NULL, I would like result from select number 2. If Select number 2. is returning NULL, I would like to use select number 3. and so on.

**Please note that I am expecting more than one row to be returned for each condition that is true - and I only want the result from either SELECT 1) 2) or 3) (in that order)**

It is important to only return results from the one single SELECT expression, so even if 2. and 3. would return something, I would only like results from 1.

The code I have right now is following that expected logic BUT when a I have more than one rows being returned by some of the below SELECTS, it gives me error:

1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

The code right now:

```
SELECT  IFNULL( (SELECT * FROM table WHERE  column = 'sometext'), IFNULL( (SELECT *    FROM table WHERE  column = 'someothertext'), IFNULL( (SELECT * FROM table WHERE  column = 'somethirdtext'), 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample data set?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(
    (SELECT col FROM t WHERE `column` = 'sometext'),
    (SELECT col FROM t WHERE `column` = 'someothertext'),
    (SELECT col FROM t WHERE `column` = 'somethirdtext')
);
```

-please, note that subquery should not return more than 1 row/column.

Comment: In SQL Server COALESCE with Subqueries is a performance issue (http://www.sillisoft.com/?p=62)  I don't know if MySQL exhibits the same behavior but it would be worth checking into before replacing ISNULL, I think.

Comment: @dazedandconfused but question is tagged as `MySQL`, not `sql-server`. In MySQL that will work fine (i.e. if rown not found, subquery's result will be treated as `NULL`)

Comment: In addition to the question tags, `ISNULL` is not the same in MySQL, ISNULL takes in MySQL takes one argument and returns a boolean value dependent on whether or not the argument IS NULL. Further more, even in SQL-Server you couldn't use `ISNULL` with 3 conditions, **and** in SQl-Server `COALESCE` with subqueries exhibits escape behaviour, i.e if the first condition is not null then the second two subqueries are not evaluated (I can't guarantee always, but in all tests I have done it does).

Comment: @alma, It is tagged mysql and the downvote wasn't from me.  I know this will work fine, I'm simply pointing out that some DBS like SQL Server will evaluate these subqueries 6 times instead of the 3 you might expect.  Just pointing it out so the OP can do his due diligence.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone keeps pointing out this is a MYSql question.  I acknowledged that in my original comment.  I'm simply saying that it is possible MySQL exhibits the same behavior as SQL Server when using COALESCE and subqueries.  If so, a COALESCE-based solution might not perform as well as he would hope.

Comment: @Gareth, you are right about the escape logic but (again, speaking for SQL Server) even if the 1st condition were true that subquery would be executed twice because SQL converts it to a CASE statement behind the scenes.  Just making sure the OP has the opportunity to see how his DBMS handles this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this slightly differently, since you can only return one row per condition anyway, I would use the following to limit the number of selects done:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table 
WHERE   column IN ('sometext', 'someothertext', 'somethirdtext')
ORDER BY CASE column 
            WHEN 'sometext' THEN 1
            WHEN 'someothertext' THEN 2
            WHEN 'somethirdtext' THEN 3
        END
LIMIT 1;
```

As pointed out in the comments, you can use FIELD for the sort too:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table 
WHERE   column IN ('sometext', 'someothertext', 'somethirdtext')
ORDER BY FIELD(column, 'sometext', 'someothertext', 'somethirdtext')
LIMIT 1;
```

I think  you can get multiple rows per condition using the following:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM    Table T
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  Column
            FROM    Table
            WHERE   column IN ('sometext', 'someothertext', 'somethirdtext')
            ORDER BY FIELD(column, 'sometext', 'someothertext', 'somethirdtext')
            LIMIT 1
        ) MinT
            ON MinT.Column = T.Column;
```

Basically the subquery `MinT` does the same as before, ordering by whichever condition matches. Then gets the value for the column of the first match and limits the whole table to this value.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b865/7)**

Comment: +1 hey gareth, instead of using `CASE`, you can also use `FIELD()` eg. `ORDER BY FIELD(column, 'sometext', 'someothertext', 'somethirdtext')`

Comment: @491243 Thanks, I've edited the answer. I do 98% of work in SQL-Server so forget about some of the features in other DBMS, it's always nice to get a reminder.

Comment: just add both, using `CASE` to be more RDBMS friendly :)

Comment: Actually, there are cases where one condition could return more than 1 row. In addition, would it be possible to introduce another column as an AND condition -> 1) SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'sometext' AND column2=1
2) SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'someothertext' AND column2=2
3) SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'somethirdtext' AND column2=3

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
      ( SELECT o.column1, o.column2
        FROM 
            ( SELECT 1 AS ord, 'sometext' AS column1, '1' AS column2 UNION ALL
              SELECT 2,        'someothertext',       '2' UNION ALL
              SELECT 3,        'somethirdtext',       '3'
            ) AS o
        WHERE EXISTS
              ( SELECT 1
                FROM table AS td 
                WHERE td.column1 = o.column1
                  AND td.column2 = o.column2
              )
        ORDER BY o.ord 
            LIMIT 1
      ) AS d
    JOIN
      table AS t
        ON  t.column1 = d.column1
        AND t.column2 = d.column2 ;
```

Comment: Results in error at line 6 ( near '2, 'someothertext', '2' UNION ALL) - any ideas whats missing? Seems like a great function, but I am not really sure if I understand it.

Comment: My mistake, missed two SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

```
%sql
select * from df where concat(name,age) in
 (select coalesce( (select distinct concat(name,age) from df where  name='Bob' and age = 25),
 (select distinct  concat(name,age) from df where name='Sam' and age = 20),
 (select distinct concat(name,age) from df where name='Rom' and age = 45)
  )
 )
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality. Perhaps you could [edit] your answer and explain how the code correctly implements the requirements as described in the [posted] question?

Answer (score -1):

MySQL isn't my daily db so I might be off on this, but can't you just use LIMIT 1 on your subqueries?

Comment: If you're going to downvote it, at least explain why.  I said up front MYSQL isn't my bag so I'm all for learning from my mistake.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it is because this is a fairly low quality answer, doesn't fully explain what limit 1 would do or show the OP how to use it. It would have been better suited as a comment on the question.