# How to execute the query with either one of the condition matched?

Tags: php, mysql

With the query below, it returns result with `(tag = '55819128' AND vsn = '001')` condition OR `(tag = '53224' AND vsn = '002')` condition.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users
WHERE
    (tag = '55819128' AND vsn = '001') OR (tag = '53224' AND vsn = '002')
```

If both the conditions are correct then it will return both results. What I looking for is if first condition returns result then no need to check for second one. If first condition returns empty then check for second condition.

So far I have done by using a `for-loop` statement.

Is there any other solutions ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I misunderstood, so deleted my answer. However, does this page help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028401/mysql-return-results-only-for-the-first-true-encountered-select-expression

Comment: @John for simplicity, I continue using loop.